# Dealing with multilevel permission on RHEL server

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel, directory

Right now, there is a mounted NFS storage on RHEL server at the following location:

`mnt/NFS/Data`

So I had to request read, write, delete permissions inside `Data` directory from the server admin.

After getting the permissions, I created three folders viz `dev`, `prod` and `test` inside the Data folder.

So I am the owner of `dev`, `prod` and `test` folders. The way I would like to modify the permissions is as follows:

Scenario 1) No one inside `prod` and `test` folders should be able to delete a file and folder including me.

Scenario 2) Everyone should be able to delete files and folders inside the dev directory.

**Questions:**

1. For scenario 1, I think I should be able to change the permission for others to read and write inside the prod and test folder since I'm the owner. But what about me? Do I need to ask the server admin to take control of permission so that everyone inside prod and test folders should have the same permissions including me?
2. Should I consider asking server admin to take the ownership from my username to root and take control of the directory dev and then assign everyone read, write and delete permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can take away write permissions from a file owner, which is sufficient if it's just to prevent you from accidentally overwriting a file.  However, a file owner can still grant themselves write access, so it's not useful as a security measure.

You don't need the `dev` folder to be owner by root to give everyone else read/write permissions.

Also keep in mind that the ability to delete a file is determined by the `write` permission on the folder, not the file itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So for scenario #1, would you suggest me to ask the server admin to take control of permission so that everyone inside prod and test folders should have the same permissions including me. I don't want to be the only one who could accidently delete a file. So the above approach of asking server admin sounds good?